# Uncaught TypeError: No method named "clear" on wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, typeerror

i'm creating a WordPress website using porto theme, I got this jquery or javascript error using a plugin.

tried this plugin on Troubleshooting Mode and it works fine without problems!

any solution, please!

i include console error details when i try to use this plugin:

```
Uncaught TypeError: No method named "clear"        bootstrap.js?ver=5.0.1:4047
at Function.dropdownInterface (bootstrap.js:4047:17)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.js:4056:18)
at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2:3003)
at s.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2:1481)
at s.fn.init.jQueryInterface [as dropdown] (bootstrap.js:4055:19)
at Object.RevyBookingFlow.bindBrandToDropdown (flow.js:423:19)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (flow.js:241:29)
at HTMLDivElement.r.complete (jquery.min.js:2:62910)
at c (jquery.min.js:2:28327)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2:29072)
```

Thank you

Comment: We can't fix a problem just from you showing us the error. We need to see the code that *produces the error*.

Comment: Hi @roryMcCrossan , thank you for the fast reply, this is the code below from the file bootstrap.js theme folder!

Answer (score 0):

```
static dropdownInterface(element, config) {
  let data = Data.get(element, DATA_KEY$7);

  const _config = typeof config === 'object' ? config : null;

  if (!data) {
    data = new Dropdown(element, _config);
  }

  if (typeof config === 'string') {
    if (typeof data[config] === 'undefined') {
      throw new TypeError(`No method named "${config}"`);
    }

    data[config]();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.